# when i login from postman i have got the error like 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value={"/logins"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logins(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("logins");
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value= {"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
    if (userExists != null) {
        bindingResult
                .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                        "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    } else {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been login successfully");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");

    }
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/admin/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome " + user.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
    modelAndView.setViewName("admin/home");
    return modelAndView;
}

}

@Service("userService")
public class Userserviceimpl implements UserService {


@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Override
public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);

}

@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {

    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setActive(1);
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("SUPERADMIN");
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
    userRepository.save(user);
}

}

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
}

public class Role {

@Id
private int roll_id;

private String role;

...

}
```

My input in postman

> [{
>      "email":"abc@gmail.com",
>      "password":"pass",
>      "name":"JOHN",
>      "active":"1",
>      "roles":[{
>          "role":"admin"
>       }]
>      }]

if i send it I have an error like this

> {
>          "timestamp": 1508938909379,
>          "status": 401,
>          "error": "Unauthorized",
>          "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
>          "path": "/login"
>      }

I have 3 tables like `user` and `role` and `user_role` in mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

Your json body is in array. Try

```
  { "email":"abc@gmail.com",
"password":"pass",
"name":"JOHN",
"active":"1",
"roles":[{ "role":"admin" }] //check this in your User.class if it is list,Ok. if not remove box brackets
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajul Shrestha,
 I have removed the array from json , now also I got the same error.
is any other problem in security configuration class?

Comment: yes! In case spring security, security class is responsible for eventual redirection based on  roles.